# DataFrame Problem: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I make a dataframe in my code and fill it in with data. Then in another function I call on that data and send it to a file. Only, when I call on it later and try to send its header to a file I get this error:

```
    column_names = clsResults.columns.tolist()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

How can this be possible? I assigned freakin headers to it when I made the dataframe!

Here is me making the frame and filling it with content:

```
def growClassifier(NUMTREES: int, DEPTH: int, X: pd.DataFrame , y: np.ndarray):
    # Split the data into training and testing sets
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, shuffle=True)

    print(f'\nBuilding classification forest with {NUMTREES} trees each {DEPTH} deep\n')

    # Initialize the week classifier 
    base_estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=DEPTH)

    start_time = time.time()

    ada = AdaBoostClassifier(estimator=base_estimator, n_estimators=NUMTREES)
    ada.fit(X_train, y_train)

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

    # Use staged_predict to get staged predictions
    staged_test_predictions = ada.staged_predict(X_test)
    

    f1_test, accuracy_test, precision_test, recall_test, buildtime_test = [], [], [], [], []
    # Iterate over staged predictions and evaluate performance at each stage
    for i, y_pred in enumerate(staged_test_predictions, start=1):
        # print(f'i:{i}\ny_pred:{y_pred}')
        accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
        accuracy_test.append(accuracy)
        
        precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average="weighted", zero_division=0)
        precision_test.append(precision)

        recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted', zero_division=0)
        recall_test.append(recall)

        f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted', zero_division=0)
        f1_test.append(f1)

        # print(f'accuracy:{accuracy}')

    adaClsResults = pd.DataFrame()

    numTrees, treeDepth = [], [] 
    for x in range(1, NUMTREES+1, 1):
        # print(i, x)
        numTrees.append(x) 
        treeDepth.append(DEPTH)
        buildtime_test.append(elapsed_time)

    if (i>40): 
        while (i < NUMTREES):
            accuracy_test.append(0)
            precision_test.append(0)
            recall_test.append(0)
            f1_test.append(0)
            buildtime_test[i] = 0
            i += 1

        adaClsResults['numTrees'] = numTrees
        adaClsResults['treeDepth'] = treeDepth
        adaClsResults['f1'] = f1_test
        adaClsResults['accuracy'] = accuracy_test
        adaClsResults['precision'] = precision_test
        adaClsResults['recall'] = recall_test
        adaClsResults['buildTime'] = buildtime_test
        return adaClsResults

    else: 
        print(f'\n\nfailed. Only boosted {i} times. Did not have  {NUMTREES} stages. running again \n\n')
        growClassifier(NUMTREES, DEPTH, X, y)
```

Ideas about how to improve the code would help also but my main concern is how come when I try to access my object later in the below function. I get the error I mentioned above.

```
def classificationRuns(model: str, task: str, allDatasets: list, clsDatasets: list, ESTNUM: int, startDEPTH: int, endDEPTH: int, MAX_RUNS: int, rawDataPath: str, aggDataPath: str ):

    for dataset in allDatasets:
        if dataset in clsDatasets: 

            # Get the data 
            X,y = parse.getClsData(dataset)
            while startDEPTH < endDEPTH: 

                runNumber = 1
                while (runNumber < MAX_RUNS + 1):
                    print(f'\nRun number:\t{runNumber}')

                    # run forest building
                    clsResults = growClassifier(ESTNUM, startDEPTH, X, y)

                    column_names = clsResults.columns.tolist()

                    # Join column names with tab separators
                    header = '\t'.join(column_names)

                    # Set file name system for raw data
                    saveRawDataHere = os.path.join(rawDataPath, dataset, f'_{ESTNUM}_{startDEPTH}_{dataset}_{model}_{task}_')

                    # add header to raw and agg file
                    with open(saveRawDataHere, 'a') as raw_file:
                        if isEmpty(saveRawDataHere):
                            raw_file.write(f"{header}\n") 
                    
                    # Set file name system for agg data
                    saveAggDataHere = os.path.join(aggDataPath, f'_{dataset}_{model}_{task}_')
                    
                    # add header to agg data file 
                    with open(saveAggDataHere, 'a') as agg_file:
                        if isEmpty(saveAggDataHere):
                            agg_file.write(f"{header}\n")

                    
                    # write data to file
                    print(f'saving data in {saveRawDataHere}')
                    clsResults.to_csv(saveRawDataHere, mode='a', index=False, header=False, sep='\t')
                    # increment counter    
                    runNumber += 1
                startDEPTH +=1
```

The main concern is

```
                    clsResults = growClassifier(ESTNUM, startDEPTH, X, y)

                    column_names = clsResults.columns.tolist()
```

This is where the error occurs.

I've tried giving it a header when I first create it by

```
    adaClsResults = pd.DataFrame(columns=X_train.colums)
```

but still end up getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`growClassifier` doesn't return anything, so effectively you're setting `clsResults` to `None`.

Then you try to access an attribute `columns` of `clsResults`, but since its value is `None`, that is not possible. This is what the error message (`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'`) is telling you.

To fix it, `growClassifier` should return a dataframe.

Comment: I have 'return adaClsResults' inside the loop where it populates it with 0s in the case were it fails. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: You have `return adaClsResults` inside `if i>40: ...`. There's no explicit return for the `else: ...` (when `i <= 40`) so your function returns `None` and that causes the error.

Comment: Ohhhhh so the inner loop returns that object but the function itself doesn't return anything? I thought having the return here would end the function and return the object too.

Comment: That's not what I mean, loops don't return anything. Your function `growClassifier` has two loops, and after the loops have ended it has a conditional statement `if i>40: ...`. If this is true, the function returns `adaClsResults`; if it's false it doesn't return anything explicitly, which means it returns `None`. Good luck!